# Problem getting post data in API via php curl call

Tags: php, curl, slim

I am trying to send a file to a slim API via curl PHP.

Actually I have a PHP file that receive a from post data and is suppose to call a slim API with the received data and slim API is going to store the data in the database. It works fine when there is no file in the data but when I send a file to API along with other data using PHP curl and set the 'content-type: multipart/form-data' I miss all the posted data in API side. I couldn't figure out what's wrong with it!!!

By the way it works well when I test the API with postman. The API successfully gets the file and save it in the storage. The problem must be in the client side where I call the API using curl and PHP.

Could anybody please help me how to setup the curl call to to make the API work ?

Thanks a lot

route.php

```
$app->post('/softwareskills/insert', SoftwareSkillsController::class . ':insert')->setName('SoftwareSkills.insert');
```

SoftwareSkillsController.php

```
class SoftwareSkillsController {


    public function insert(Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
    {

            $params= $request->getParsedBody();
            $file = $request->getUploadedFiles();
            var_dump($params); // return empty array!
            var_dump($file); // return empty array!

    }
}
```

upload.php

```
<?php
     // $_POST and $_FILES to send them via php CURL

$tmpfile = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$filename = basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
$filemime = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];

$data = array(
    "StNo" => $_POST['StNo'],
    "SoftwareName" =>  $_POST['SoftwareName'],
    "proficiency" => $_POST['proficiency'],
    "attachment" => new CURLFile($tmpfile,$filemime,$filename)
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://myapi.com/softwareskills/insert",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "content-type: multipart/form-data"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Stop trying to set the Content-Type header yourself, and let cURL handle that on its own. `multipart/form-data` makes little sense by itself, it needs to include the _boundary_ that is used in the request body to separate the parameters from each other. cURL should set the correct value, including the boundary, by itself.

Comment: If I remove the content-type from the header then on the API side `$params` gives posted datas but `$file` is still empty and I am unable to save the uploaded file! What is wrong in my code?!

Comment: I removed `http_build_query` and `contente-type: multipart/form-data` and it worked! Thanks for your helpful comment @04FS!

Comment: alternatively if you don't mind a third party library, you can look it [guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) to make the post request